# error in spaces printHourglass

Tags: java, loops, recursion

```
public static void printHourglass(int size , char symbol) {
    printHourglass(size, 0, symbol);
}

public static void printHourglass(int size, int s, char symbol) {
    stars(size, s,symbol);
    if (size > 2) {
        printHourglass(size - 2, s + 1, symbol);
        stars(size, s,symbol);
    }
}

public static void stars(int n, int s, char symbol) {
    if (s > 0) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        stars(n, s - 1 , symbol);
    } else if (n > 0) {
        System.out.print(symbol);
        stars(n - 1 , s, symbol);
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

my code is a little good but i want its result to be like this

Given the size of hourglass is 5. The expected output of printHourglass():
the black marks is spaces and i want my code to print spaces like the one below

Remarks: The space in the following output is represented as dark box and the new line is shown as paragraph mark (¶).

```
?????
█???█
██?██
█???█
?????
```

my code output right now is like this without spaces on the right how and i want it to print spaces like the one above  :

```
?????¶
█???¶
██?¶
█???¶
?????¶
```

Failed

[see this link please](http://postimg.org/image/wt4orcrgp/)

Comment: Can you share an working example of your code not only parts.

Comment: Formatting the code (intendation) might help...

Comment: thats my whole code sir

Comment: How you know that? You otput to console it did not show new lines.

Comment: yeah sir i pasted an explanation above and also a link to a picture that shows what i meant by spaces and thank u all for trying to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int subtract = (int)Math.floor(size / 2);

    for(int i = size - subtract; i >= 1; i--){

      for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){          
          System.out.print(' ');
        }

      for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){          
          System.out.print(symbol);
        }

      for(int j = i; j < size - subtract; j++){
         System.out.print(' ');
        }

          System.out.println();
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= size - subtract; i++)
    {

     for(int j=i;j<size - subtract;j++){
         System.out.print(' ');
        }

     for(int j=1;j<=i*2-1;j++){         
         System.out.print(symbol);
        }

     for(int j = i; j < size - subtract; j++){
         System.out.print(" ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

thanks for every one whom tried to help me and the id the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you change your stars method signature as below, you should be able to work it out

```
public static void stars(int size, int beg, int end, char symbol)
```

Comment: how sir be more specific please and thank u so much for ur help

Comment: @Javabeginner As you're working recursively, you can't track the beginning and ending spaces with one variable, so use two.

Comment: i dont want to track it i just want to add spaces at the right side that is  all like above instead of black marks

Comment: its perfect on the left but its not ok on the right side like shown above

Comment: @Javabeginner You're recursively decrementing your s variable, given that, after you write the leading spaces and the symbols, how can you know how many ending spaces to write? Answer: by passing in and handling a variable that tells you how many ending spaces to write - handle it the same way you do the beginning spaces but after the symbols have been written.

Comment: can u show me how sir and i will be thankful if u dont mind plz